# How to manually add PIL module to pyinstaller exe?

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I am creating a standalone exe file with pyinstaller but I get the 'modulenotfound' error when I try to run it. It cannot locate the PIL module even though it is in the same 'site-packages' folder as all my other modules. How do I tell it where the PIL module is?

I have tried the following flags in my cmd line when using pyinstaller, none of them worked:

```
--hidden-import=Pillow
--hidden-import='PIL'
--hidden-import='Pillow'
```

My script uses the following line of code in regards to the PIL module:

```
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Everything works fine in the script, it is only when I use pyinstaller that I have a problem.

Comment: Try `--hidden-import PIL`.  BTW have you upgrade PyInstaller to the latest version (4.0)? `PIL` (Pillow) is included automatically in my PyInstaller 4.0 and Python 3.8.5 under Windows 7.

Comment: I'm running pyinstaller 4.0, python 3.8.3, and windows 10. I tried `--hidden-import PIL` but it did not work and is still giving me the modulenotfound error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I had to install pyinstaller within the PyCharm terminal, then I had to run pyinstaller within the PyCharm terminal as well using

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w "foo.py"
```

I was previously running a cmd right from my file directory outside of PyCharm and running pyinstaller there, but running pyinstaller inside PyCharm works.

Comment: This is because pycharm uses a virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the library folder of `PIL` from the Python folder within the drive and move it to the same folder as the `.py` file, then I run the cmd with the line `--hidden-import=PIL` and it just works, just remember to put the executable file in the same directory you put within your line of codes, might not run if it's not in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

To whom might help
I got lots of issues trying to user pymssql with Pyinstaller and I finally got it right so posting here might help someone
after you install pymssql using pip install pymssql

use this parameters in pyintaller to get it included

```
--onefile --paths=.\venv\ --hidden-import='pymssql' --hidden-import='uuid' --collect-all='pymssql' --collect-all='uuid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `datas=[]` parameter in the generated `.spec` file to include the path to the local **'PIL'** folder.
This is well-detailed by BoobyTrap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53468495/13712347)

**OR**

`pyinstaller --add-data="<path_to_PIL_location>:PIL" --hidden-import=PIL <python_file_to_run>`

```bash
pyinstaller --add-data=./venv/lib/Python3.11/site-packages/PIL:PIL -hidden-import=PIL app.py
```

**0R**

The required Python modules for the application and pyinstaller should be in the same virtual environment. This worked for me