# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL', when convert py to exe in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, auto-py-to-exe

I wrtoe a program using tkinter module which is working well in vs code but when I transfer it to exe by auto-py-to-exe, I'm getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'" while I installed Pillow in my env.
any solution?

Comment: mabye this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057842/how-to-manually-add-pil-module-to-pyinstaller-exe

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I've added it to the .spec file under hidden imports and it worked. Make sure to do pip uninstall PIL since it can cause conflicts with Pillow.

```
hiddenimports=['Pillow']
```